# Independence of Brownian bridge and Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

Let $B(t)$, $t \ge 0$ be the standard Brownian motion. Define Brownian bridge as
$$
X(t) = B(t) - tB(1), \qquad 0 \le t \le 1.
$$
We see that
\begin{align*}
cov(X(t),B(1)) &= cov(B(t)-tB(1),B(1))\\&= cov(B(t),B(1)) - tcov(B(1),B(1)) = t - t = 0.
\end{align*}
Hence, since $X(t)$ is a Gaussian process, it is independent of $B(1)$.

Now my question:

> Let $0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_n < 1$. Is the vector
>   $$
> (X(t_1),X(t_2),\dots,X(t_n))
> $$
>   independent of $B(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since the variable are jointly normal the fact that $cov(X(t_i),B(1))=0$ for each $i$ implies that $(X(t_1),X(t_2),...,X(t_n))$ is independent of $B(1)$.

Comment: I see that the vector is jointly normal but how this implies that it is independent of $B(1)$?

Comment: The variance covariance matrix of the $n+1$- tuple has a block from and this implies independence from the from of the density function or from the characteristic function). @xen

Comment: Thanks! So in fact we have even more: random variables $X(t_1), X(t_2),\dots,X(t_n),B(1)$ are independent, right?

Comment: No, that is not true. $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2)$ are not independent. For example $cov(X(\frac 1 2), X(\frac  1 3))=\frac 1 6$. @xen

Comment: Great. Now I think that I understand.